# Can service fabric actors of same type use different versions of same dll?

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

The dll being loaded using Assembly.Load has a long running method that returns large dataset, I am thinking of creating AppDomains to run different versions of this dll. However, I have not used AppDomains, so I am not sure about the complexity and the performance of Marshalling/serialization across AppDomain boundaries.

Therefore, I wonder if I can bypass AppDomains by taking advantage of micro services architecture in Service Fabric before exploring with AppDomains.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a different actor service that uses the different version of the DLL. Otherwise you will have serious side-effects(bugs, maintainability) of using different versions of the same dll in a single actor.

Comment: @alltej The problem is that these dlls are loaded dynamically,  from database. I was hoping that these actors would run as different processes thus would have different AppDomains, but I was wrong. If Assembly.Load method has an overload method for reloading assembly or a corresponding Unload method, that would solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with the Micro Service Architecture you are pretty much going with loading the dll in a different process, which might be simpler but will have the dependency on the ServiceFabric.

With AppDomains the complexity is basically if you are passing data around different appdomain. If thats not the case I believe AppDomain is the right approach for this scenario.